# Use an additional condition/parameter for Enumerable.GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq, join, iqueryable, enumerable

I looked at the documentation for the GroupJoin method at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb535047(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't see how one would create the join on more than one property. Below is an example on how my current code looks like.

```
  var test = _MasterData.LinqCustomerGroup.GroupJoin(_MasterData.LinqDisposallistDisposalArticles,
                                                           c => c.Guid,
                                                           d => d.CustomerGroup,
                                                           (c, ds) => new { c, ds = ds })                                                    
                                                .SelectMany(z => z.ds.DefaultIfEmpty(), (c, d) => new { CustomerGroupID = c.c.CustomerGroupID, Description = c.c.Description, Disposallist = d.Disposallist }));
```

I would like to have the join be performed on an additional parameter. Inside d is an attribute called Article. I want the function to only join elements that have Article == "value".

Comment: I had same issue this morning that I got a warning to use GroupJoin.  Found I was looking at a Class object rather than a property inside the class.  Fixed issue using myclass.XX instead of myclass (no property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to "join on an additional condition", but to *filter* out all elements in `LinqDisposallistDisposalArticles` that have an `Article` different from `"value"`.

If that's correct, simply use `Where` on that sequence before joining:

```
var test = _MasterData.LinqCustomerGroup.GroupJoin(
                // filter inner sequence
                _MasterData.LinqDisposallistDisposalArticles.Where(d => d.Article == "value"),
                c => c.Guid,
                d => d.CustomerGroup,
                (c, ds) => new { c, ds = ds })                                                    
           .SelectMany(....);
```